# ArrayAdapter in Fragment - Android

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I get some error I don't know why. I'm populating ListView with array adapter from string in fragment. I'm using this fragment as main screen to be shown in main activity
This is my code

```
public class HomePage extends Fragment {

private ListView lvHomePage;
private String[] items;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home_page, container, false);

    items = getActivity().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.test);
    lvHomePage = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.lvHomePage);

    lvHomePage.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 , items));

    return view;
}
}
```

I get this output error:

```
09-18 21:07:27.315: E/AndroidRuntime(3839): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-18 21:07:27.315: E/AndroidRuntime(3839): Process: com.kiko.bmgu.crnobelo, PID: 3839
09-18 21:07:27.315: E/AndroidRuntime(3839): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo     com.kiko.bmgu.crnobelo/com.kiko.bmgu.crnobelo.activities.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-18 21:07:27.315: E/AndroidRuntime(3839):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)\
09-18 21:07:27.315: E/AndroidRuntime(3839):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
09-18 21:07:27.315: E/AndroidRuntime(3839):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
09-18 21:07:27.315: E/AndroidRuntime(3839):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
09-18 21:07:27.315: E/AndroidRuntime(3839):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
09-18 21:07:27.315: E/AndroidRuntime(3839):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
09-18 21:07:27.315: E/AndroidRuntime(3839):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
09-18 21:07:27.315: E/AndroidRuntime(3839):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-18 21:07:27.315: E/AndroidRuntime(3839):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
09-18 21:07:27.315: E/AndroidRuntime(3839):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
09-18 21:07:27.315: E/AndroidRuntime(3839):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
09-18 21:07:27.315: E/AndroidRuntime(3839):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Naive Method)
09-18 21:07:27.315: E/AndroidRuntime(3839): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-18 21:07:27.315: E/AndroidRuntime(3839):     at com.kiko.bmgu.fragments.HomePage.onCreateView(HomePage.java:25)
09-18 21:07:27.315: E/AndroidRuntime(3839):     at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1700)
09-18 21:07:27.315: E/AndroidRuntime(3839):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:890)
09-18 21:07:27.315: E/AndroidRuntime(3839):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
09-18 21:07:27.315: E/AndroidRuntime(3839):     at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:684)
09-18 21:07:27.315: E/AndroidRuntime(3839):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1447)
09-18 21:07:27.315: E/AndroidRuntime(3839):     at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5240)
09-18 21:07:27.315: E/AndroidRuntime(3839):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2168)
09-18 21:07:27.315: E/AndroidRuntime(3839):     ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`lvHomePage` must be null. Use `lvHomePage = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.lvHomePage);` instead.

Answer (score 11):

Try this way

```
 private ListView lvHomePage;
    private String[] items;
    private View view;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home_page, container, false);

    return view;
}

@Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    items = view.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.test);
    lvHomePage = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.lvHomePage);

    lvHomePage.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(view.getContext(),
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 , items));
   ...
}
```

Comment: as AIL said, I should use view instead of getActivity()

Answer (score 3):

The problem is within `lvHomePage = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.lvHomePage);`
that's wrong you should get the root view is `view`  not the activity 
so it should be like this

`lvHomePage = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.lvHomePage);`